# Choropleth map with folium - python

Tags: python, choropleth, folium

Im having trouble to  do choropleth map for brazil state
Im using folium library to do it as follows:

```
import folium
import json

with open('br-states.json') as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)

m = folium.Map(
    location=[-18.826592, -55.212558],
    zoom_start=4,
    tiles='OpenStreetMap')

m.choropleth(
geo_data=d,
name='choropleth',
data=new_data,
columns=['State', 'QTY'],
key_on='feature.id',
fill_color='YlGn',
fill_opacity=0.7,
line_opacity=0.2,
legend_name='Unemployment Rate (%)'
)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)

m
```

My data is called `new_data`

[image]

I dont know if there is some problem with the code or there is problem with my `json` file called `br-state`(might be related to the coordinates used by the autor of this file or something else)

I get the map however the map does not turn to choropleth map

Any suggetion will be highly appreciated

Comment: Everything looks right from my perspective.  I would suspect the json file you're using.  Does `feature.id` exist in that file?

Comment: I also belived on that, however, I never handled json file and I'm confusing, this is a small part of the json file                                           
`u'objects': {u'estados': {u'bbox': [-73.97741220933203,
    -33.74579986956992,
    -34.81727575186676,
    5.24981966486962],
   u'geometries': [{u'arcs': [[0, 1, 2]],
     u'id': u'AC',
     u'properties': {u'nome': u'Acre'},
     u'type': u'Polygon'},
    {u'arcs': [[3, 4, 5, 6]],
     u'id': u'AL',
     u'properties': {u'nome': u'Alagoas'},
     u'type': u'Polygon'}`, I still dont know what to put on `key_on`

Comment: ok, keying on `feature.id` is common for most geojson files, but your key appears to be geometries.id.  eg `key_on='geometries.id'`

Answer (score 1):

I am using this JSON file: https://github.com/datalivre/Conjunto-de-Dados/blob/master/br_states.json
Look at the code, it's a bit different from yours. You do not need to convert the JSON file to a dictionary. Here an image with the result that I got. [folium br_states](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fa3e4.png)

```
import folium
import pandas as pd


new_data = pd.read_excel('new_data.xlsx')

state_geo = 'br_states.json'
mapa = folium.Map(
    location=[-15.77972, -47.92972],
    zoom_start=3
)

folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=state_geo,
    name='Estados QTY',
    data=new_data,
    columns=['State','QTY'],
    key_on='feature.id',
    fill_color='YlOrBr',
    fill_opacity=0.7,
    line_opacity=0.1,
    legend_name='Insert legend'
).add_to(mapa)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(mapa)
mapa.save('index.html')
mapa
```